# Can someone please explain to me the response value (An array with 69 items contained) of Authorize.net

Tags: authorize.net

I'm trying to integrate a payment gateway (Authorize.Net, AIM) into my website (PHP v7.0 + Apache2.5), I do it with CURL, like this:

```
    $delimiter = $params['delimiter'];
    $post_url = AUTHORIZE_POST_URL;
    $post_values = array(
        "x_login" => AUTHORIZE_API_LOGIN_ID,
        "x_tran_key" => AUTHORIZE_API_TRANSACTION_KEY,
        "x_recurring_billing" => FALSE,
        "x_version" => "3.1",
        "x_delim_data" => "TRUE",
        "x_delim_char" => $delimiter,
        "x_relay_response" => "FALSE",
        "x_type" => "AUTH_CAPTURE",
        "x_method" => "CC",
        "x_card_num" => $params['card_number'],
        "x_exp_date" => $params['card_expire_date'],
        "x_amount" => (float) $params['order_amount'],
        "x_description" => $params['order_description'],
        "x_first_name" => $params['order_first_name'],
        "x_last_name" => $params['order_last_name'],
        "x_address" => $params['order_address_address'],
        "x_city" => $params['order_address_city'],
        "x_state" => $params['order_address_state'],
        "x_zip" => $params['order_address_zip']
    );

    $post_string = http_build_query($post_values);
    $request = curl_init($post_url); 
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string); 
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
    $post_response = curl_exec($request); 
    curl_close($request); 
    return $post_response;
```

The response will be an Array with 69 item contained, I want to know each of the items means.

Also, I want to integrate the AVS and CCV, I followed the instruction to enable the AVS Filter and CCV Filter in my account of Authorize.net, but somehow, it doesn't work.

Any thoughts will be appreciated!!!

Plus: the response array looks like this:

> ["1","1","1","This transaction has been approved.","RPPG48","Y","40014513637","","","3.00","CC","auth_capture","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","3CDC8404F9E62C3D8F2C0259623F3265","P","2","","","","","","","","","","","XXXX0015","MasterCard","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authorize.Net AIM is deprecated, but you can find legacy documentation at https://developer.authorize.net/api/upgrade_guide/#aim

Comment: @Jack rhdlr works for Authorize.Net.

Comment: see this PDF for more info https://www.authorize.net/content/dam/authorize/documents/AIM_guide.pdf

Comment: @JohnConde, THANK YOU, That's exactly what I want!

Comment: @rhldr, THANK YOU TOO!